# Python issue with CTRL-V in Tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, hex, tkinter-entry

In the Entry widget, I tried to restrict values to only hexadecimal using `validatecommand` and a function to verify if the entry value is in 'abcdef0123456789'. The problem lies in the fact that "CTRL+V" (Paste) doesn't work when I use it to insert value. There is no problem with "CTRL+C" and "CTRL+X" (Copy and Cut).

Is that a way to restrict the entry to hexadecimal value and in same time allow the use of CTRL-V to Paste/insert value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is that a way to restrict the entry to hexadecimal value and in same time allow the use of CTRL-V to Paste/insert value?

Yes. Arguably the simplest method is to use the `validatecommand` to check that all of the characters in the widget are hex digits. The `validatecommand` doesn't care how the characters are entered (typing vs cut/paste).

In the following example, `'%P'` tells tkinter to pass the new value of the entry widget if the edit is allowed. We can then use the `re` module to see if the new value is composed of only zero or more hex digits.

```
import tkinter as tk
import re

def validate(possible_new_value):
    if re.match(r'^[0-9a-fA-F]*$', possible_new_value):
        return True
    return False

root = tk.Tk()
entry = tk.Entry(root, validate="key", 
                 validatecommand=(root.register(validate), '%P'))
entry.pack(padx=20, pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.